# Difference between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to differnece between two dates with datediff funcation but when date is same (Start Date and End date) then output coming zero but i need as 1 im using this method

```
CEILING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),H.FromDateTimeLocal-H.ToDateTimeLocal))
```

but getting error

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

Please help me out

Comment: You are doing `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ...`, so what is not clear about that error message?

Comment: What is the datatype of `FromDateTimeLocal` & `ToDateTimeLocal`

Comment: I don't see any datediff func in your code.

Comment: `Ceiling` function works with numbers, and you are using this function with `varchar(10)` ?

Comment: welcome to SO. please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I understand that H.FromDateTimeLocal and H.ToDateTimeLocal are datetime columns where are you using datetiff function. You are subtracting H.ToDateTimeLocal from H.FromDateTimeLocal. This would give you resulting date in varchar format upon which you are trying to run convert and then ceiling function. Don't do that.

Comment: You can't "subtract" one date from another using `H.FromDateTimeLocal-H.ToDateTimeLocal`  in T-SQL like you can do in standard SQL

Comment: Do you want to only handle the case when it is zero or do you want to round up in all cases? When you say you need 1, what time granule do you mean? One day? One minute? Sample data and expected results is in some ways less fun for the reader but tends to result in better answers for the OP.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, H.ToDateTimeLocal, H.FromDateTimeLocal)
```

Comment: I suspect it is because your answer will yield 0 when both dates are the same (which is exactly what he is trying to avoid).  By the way, I am not the one who downvoted you.